# Python PyInstaller no response

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I install PyInstaller step by step like every guide says, but it just won't work. 
When i try run something like that `python makespec.py --help` makespec.py just no response. No error or something, it just return empty line -

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2ZGS.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do,

```
python pyinstaller.py --help
```

Comment: this would be a better answer if you drew attention to what was different from what the asker is doing, and why it matters.

Comment: Oh yeah, i just try to use something like "makespec.py -F -w -X example.py" with pyinstaller.py - "pyinstaller.py -F -w -X example.py", and it's work! Thank you!